# Lots of bots making fake calls

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables

I have a small VPS with Apache + php on which i host just a small blog.

I've been looking through its logs and seen tons of calls that (i guess) have the hostname faked. Here's [a sample](http://pastebin.com/qSWsqyFL). Obviously these calls have nothing to do with the site I'm hosting. I blocked about 20 ips that were showing up more often by dropping them in iptables but the log file is still getting fat.

I've looked in Apache config to make sure that ProxyRequests is set to Off.

Is there any better way to stop them?

Comment: Looks like standard [Internet Background Radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_background_noise) to me.  Not much you can do, other then pulll the plug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache is returning a `404` error in response to the proxy attempts, so that means you server is not behaving as an open proxy (yay!). For all intents and purposes, as long as they're not hurting the performance of your system (which is highly unlikely), these are harmless - just ignore them.

Comment: You're always gonna see background traffic like this, which shouldn't be a problem unless it's a lot. You should make sure your 404 page is lightweight, i.e. requires little to no dynamic processing to render, so you can handle a lot of this traffic without increasing your load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was curious to find that Apache still lets these through even if the site is setup as a vhost that specifies a hostname.

Comment: Requests without a `Host` header will be handled by the default vhost.